# jQuery Select box value

Tags: jquery, select

How do i change the select box value based on the border width of a clicked div.

```
<select id="borderWidth">
    <option>none</option>
    <option>1px</option>
    <option>2px</option>
    <option>3px</option>
    <option>4px</option>
    <option>5px</option>
</select>

<div style="border:1px solid #cccccc"></div>
<div style="border:5px solid #cccccc"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AjxTA/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/F5Gms/

```
$('div').click(function() {
    var x = $(this).css('border-top-width');
    $("#borderWidth").val(x);
})
```

Comment: hehe yeah.. just realized that ;)